# need to recover chrome passwords, but the DB is empty

Tags: google-chrome

Good morning,

i need to recover my passwords from a chrome browser (no google acc attached and not logged in to chrome). In the past i always got "Login Data", but the DB is now empty. The chrome browser had passwords stored, so they have to be somewhere.

did chrome change the location, where they store the passwords? it is kinda hard to find any information about this topic...

installed chrome: 78.0.3904.70

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, that Chrome moved the passwords to their corresponding profile sub-directories: Profile1, Profile2, ... . There i was able to find all my passwords.